# Invoke bean method from h: or p:button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF2.2.

Can I invoke a bean method from `onclick` attribute of `h:button`?

Or can I do it from PrimeFaces `p:button` component?

I want to use `button` in order to apply bootstrap css.

Comment: [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml), since you have explicitly mentioned PrimeFaces.

Comment: Does <p:remoteCommand> renders as html <button> ?

Comment: No. You can invoke a bean method via `<p:remoteCommand>` which can be triggered by an appropriate JavaScript event such as `onclick="func()"` `<p:remoteCommand name="func" action(Listener)="#{bean.listener}".../>`.

Comment: So you want to make all your pages complex, just to use bootstrap css? Why not use [BootsFaces](http://www.bootsfaces.net) then? Wayyyyy easier and based on PrimeFaces

Comment: I didn't find good documentation / examples on BootsFaces.  I made a try but didn't work as expected.  Do you know of a site with examples?

Comment: @BalusC I don´t think this question is duplicate, because neither h:button or h:commandButton render as <button> ... </button>